# Iterate multiple list of dictionary - Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I want to iterate through multiple, in this case two, lists of dictionary using the `loop` statement.

**Variables:**

```
my_team:
    - { name: 'testuser1', groups: 'wheel' }
    - { name: 'testuser2', groups: 'root' }

your_team:
    - { name: 'testuser3', groups: 'wheel' }
    - { name: 'testuser4', groups: 'root' }
```

**Code:**

```
- name: Add several users
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
  loop:
    - "{{ my_team }}"
    - "{{ your_team }}"
```

I believe using the dash (`-`) followed by the list will make it a nested list, but also makes the code more readable. Is the only solution to flatten them in the `loop` section itself, or should I try to merge both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the lists

```yaml
- name: Add several users
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
  loop: "{{ my_team|d([], true) + your_team|d([], true) }}"
```

Q: ***"Could it also handle empty lists, or empty variables of type NoneType by defaulting to empty lists?"***

A: Yes. It can. See the filter [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default)

> *"If you want to use default with variables that evaluate to false you have to set the second parameter to true."*

Comment: Yes, perfect! However, would you recommend to me creating a new variable by using that expression to make it more readable, but also to handle "empty" lists? What I mean, could it also handle empty lists, or empty variables of type `NoneType` by defaulting to empty lists?

Comment: Yes. You can. I updated the answer.

Comment: Pfft. Legend. Sorry for adding additonal question.